# Real Time Scenarios to use singleton class in android

Tags: java, android

I know about singleton class. but i want to know Real Time Scenarios to use singleton class in android . Can anyone give me examples in android to use and with benefits of that scenario..

Comment: What do you mean by Real Time?

Comment: Explain briefly what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Two real good scenarios

- Extend your application class and use it's instance to get access to the app context within any class
- SQL Database is a good idea to be a singleton class

Here is an example of App usage

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance = null;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Access String in R

```
public class DummyClass {
    private void getAppString(){
        String r = MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.app_name);
    }
}
```